# Why are in IE >= 9 using border-radius:[value] fixed child Elements clipped?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

If I use css `border-radius:[some value]` for a parent element and have a fixed positioned child element, in Internet Explorer the child element gets 'clipped' into the parent. If I use `border-radius:0` in the parent element, the result is ok (but without a border radius).

This is IE >= 9 only. Other browsers behave like expected.

Here's a [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/L98Md/) showing what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's to do with the way it handles the overflow. If you remove the overflow property entirely, IE9 treats those tooltips the same as decent browsers.

Comment: True, but I need that overflow-y. Anyway, it's still not clear what `border-radius` has to do with it.